# onPostExecute() doesn't wait for thread to be finished inside doInBackground()?

Tags: android

I have a following AyncTask, I want to set OnClickListener on a button which gets created after the result of fetch from internet is complete, but **onPostExecute** gets executed without waiting for fetch from internet to complete.

```
private class findUserByEmail extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        String userEmail = params[0];

        System.out.println(" passed userEmail ============= " + userEmail);

        mHttpClient.fetchUserSecurityDetails(userEmail, new HttpClient.UserSecurityCallback() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (mHttpClient.getResponseMessage().contains("User details found")) {

                    isUserValid = true;


                } else {

                    isUserValid = false;
                    View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                    Snackbar.make(view, "User does not exist", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "User does not exist");

                }

            }
        });
        System.out.println(" Returned isUserValid ============= " + isUserValid);
        return isUserValid;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isValid) {

        isUserValid = isValid;

        if(isUserValid!=null && isUserValid) {

            mWaitingIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            mUserForgotPasswordLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mUserVerifySecurityQuestionLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            TextView mUserFetchedSecurityQuestion = findViewById(R.id.tv_userSequrityQuestion);
            mUserFetchedSecurityQuestion.setText(getSecurityDetails(mHttpClient.getResponseMessage()));

            mEditTextSecurityAnswer =  findViewById(R.id.edt_userAnswerInput);

            mVerifyUser  = findViewById(R.id.btn_verifyUserDetails);

            mVerifyUser.setOnClickListener(LoginActivity.this);

        } else {
            View view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            Snackbar.make(view, "Not able to search user at this time", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Not able to search user at this time");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Then it would seem that you don't actually need an `AsyncTask` at all. The `mHttpClient.fetchUserSecurityDetails()` method seems to be already asynchronous itself, which is why it takes a callback as an argument. Get rid of the `AsyncTask`, and just do whatever you wanted to do in `onPostExecute()` at the end of the `HttpClient.UserSecurityCallback`'s `run()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Once you return from doInBackground, onPostExecute method would be called. In your case the method  mHttpClient.fetchUserSecurityDetails results are based on the callback events and doInbackground does not wait for it.
As doInBackground runs in Non UI thread, you could make changes to your method return synchronously instead of sending result in callback.

Change your method to return result instead of passing through callback.

```
 isUserValid  = mHttpClient.fetchUserSecurityDetails(userEmail);
```

Another option would be make current thread to sleep until you get call back event and then return from doInbackground method once your get back result.